# How can I have 2 foreign keys in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Simple question but seems very difficult for me. I need 2 foreign keys in my table and after, will use query builder to get specific columns that I need.

**Here is an image:**

[image]

Currently, the `ProductID` already has a relation with my `Products` table. What I want now is to have another relation with my `CustomerID` to my `CustomerProducts` table. Any idea or reference on how to do it?

Comment: Click on that nifty little `[Add]` button in the dialog on the right and define your second foreign key ......

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use code to create the foreign keys?

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT NameYourFK FOREIGN KEY (YourColumn) REFERENCES YourOtherTable (YourOtherIdentityColumn)
```